# How to Combine Multiple Excel into one with Talend

Tags: excel, talend

I'm a new in Talend and need some help.

I want to write data in the same excel file containing different sheets, I have 2 tFileOuputExcel, I put the same file name and different sheet names,

In output the data is written only in the first sheet but not in the second sheet.

Below is the screenshot of my job.
[image: job screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

You can use tFileExcel-Components 13.3 by Jan Lolling on Talend Exchange. We have been using it in our project without any issues. You can use

1. tFileExcelWorkbookOpen - to open excel file (blank template file)
2. tFileExcelSheetOutput - to write to each sheet of the workbook opened above.
3. tFileExcelWorkbookSave - to save the excel file

Comment: thank you for your response in my case i can't install extern compnenets ( I don't have permisssion) but i will rephrase my problem.

Comment: you have to just download it, put each folder like tFileExcelWorkbookOpen in "usercomponents" directory (create if not exists) where other directories of Talend Studio executable are. Then specify this directory's path in Preferences --> Talend --> components. Thats it.

Answer (score 0):

in 2nd tFileOutputExcel select checkbox "Append Existing File"